# Nginx-to enable autostart

Tags: nginx

I installed the docker container in my ubuntu 13.10. Along with this nginx webserver also

installed.But every time i want to type this command

service nginx restart.

so how can i autorun the nginx?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Start nginx at ubuntu startup**

Check runlevel

```
^_^[root@easyengine:~]# runlevel 
N 2
```

My ubuntu runlevel is 2 so i'm edit the following file

```
mv /etc/rc2.d/K20nginx /etc/rc2.d/S20nginx
```

Now restart the system

**Method 2: rc.local**
Add following line before the `exit 0`

```
service nginx start
```

Comment: Please, could your explain method 1? Why renaming a file fix the issue?

Comment: `runlevel` command check and display current runlevel.
Now in above example its runlevl 2 so we need to rename killed K20nginx nginx file with start nginx file S20nginx

By default linux start all the runlevl script which start with S and Killed which are start with K

More info - https://miteshshah.github.io/linux/basics/system-initialization/#system-initialization-1